# How to have nginx forward the HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO header?

Tags: nginx

I'm chainging my setup from

```
nginx > apache/php
```

to

```
haproxy > nginx > apache/php
```

(using haproxy 1.5-dev18 with ssl support compiled in)

Both nginx and haproxy are setup correctly to set the HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO header. However, when nginx gets the ssl traffic from haproxy, it sees the connection as http and sets the header as so.

How can I set nginx to forward the HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO header if it exists, but otherwise continue setting it based on the connection?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I figured out how to solve this. The problem was that nginx was overwriting the header set by haproxy on this line of my config:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

I fixed it by adding in this:

```
map $http_x_forwarded_proto $thescheme {
     default $scheme;
     https https;
 }
```

and changing the proxy_set_header line to use the new scheme:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $thescheme;
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, your before and after `proxy_set_header` lines are the same.

Comment: `$scheme` vs `$thescheme`.

Comment: Isn't this in some rare cases insecure? If a web browser sends a HTTP request to haproxy, and haproxy then sends a HTTPS request to Nginx — then the `default $scheme` case will happen, setting `$thescheme` to HTTPS although in fact the request (to haproxy) is insecure HTTP. — To avoid that, what about: `default $http_x_forwarded_proto;  ''  $scheme;`, so if haproxy says HTTP it'll be respected.

Comment: That is suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21911864/694469 (i.e. `default $http_x_forwarded_proto;`).

Comment: look like are you forcefully sending the secure request

Answer (score 17):

I had the same need with AWS ELB

Here is my solving line:

```
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
```

Comment: Should I bet setting `$http_x_forwarded_proto` somewhere? What is that?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-Proto
$http_x_forwarded_proto is the NGINX implementation

Comment: You answer just solved an issue I've been hammering at for 3 days!
Every other post on the subject of aws load balancers with https advocate `proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;`, which doesn't work

Comment: $http_x_forwarded_proto is the way nginx exposes the X-Forwarded-Proto header. See the docs for "$http_name" in http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables

Comment: Doesn't this just copy the header value from the upstream request? Shouldn't nginx do this automatically?

Comment: I used `proxy_set_header  x-forwarded-proto https;` in my setup and it finally worked. Mine is used with node.js as the upstream.

Comment: When I do this my application gets `X-Forwarded-Proto=http,https`

Answer (score 1):

I can't just comment so I post this as an answer : Could you give us part or all of your nginx configuration so we can see what's wrong with it ? Possibly your HAProxy config too ?

The first problem I can think of is that your HAProxy is doing ssl termination.
To sum it up, to offload your backend servers, a load balancer can be configured to do all the ssl thing, and then communicate with your backend servers in HTTP.
Like the scheme here : http://blog.exceliance.fr/2012/09/10/how-to-get-ssl-with-haproxy-getting-rid-of-stunnel-stud-nginx-or-pound/

To give you a good answer to your question, could you check you don't have any loopback problem in your http<>https config ? Maybe then you could redirect http to http, https to https, and then force http to be redirected to https.

Could you check too that you have enabled ssl passthrough in your HAProxy config ?

Comment: Did you resolve your problem ?

Comment: I figured it out. Your answer didn't help directly, but that second link helped me figure out a way to solve it. Thanks.